# Which browsers do not support lowercase 'location' in php header redirect?

Tags: php, http-headers

I am fairly sure that I have read about:

```
<?php header("location: ...") ?>
```

Not working on ALL browsers. Some VERY old ones require the "location" bit to be written with a capital letter L:

```
<?php header("Location: ...") ?>
```

But I can't find documentation to back this up. The PHP manual does not mention this (anymore?). Anybody any idea?

Note: I am not looking for the best way to do this. I am looking for documentation on browser behavior.

Comment: server side code not depend on browser behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per RFC 2616, "Hypertext Transfer Protocol", [section 4.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.2):

> Each header field consists of a name followed by a colon (":") and the
> field value. Field names are case-insensitive.

I have never seen and can't find any sources that list any browsers that do not follow the RFC specification, so I wouldn't worry about the capitalization of the header field text. Having said that, I tend to use `Location`.